# How to select previous element in Html page via python with some conditions

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

hello i'm trying to get some data form a web site and then i should find the last element i worked with it last time in the page and select previews element of the first element please check my code and i explain more complete in the my example :

this is the example HTML code :

```
<div class="post" id="7517049">
    <div class="p-head">
        <div class="p-c p-c-time"><span class="p-time" data="1554741054" title="2019-04-08 @ 21:00:54 ( Your Time )"><span class="t-n-m">45</span> <span class="t-u">mins</span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="p-c p-c-cat"><span class="p-cat c-5 c-7 "><a href="http://predb.me?cats=tv" class="c-adult">TV</a><a href="http://predb.me?cats=tv-hd" class="c-child">HD</a></span></div>
        <div class="p-c p-c-title">
            <h2><a class="p-title" href="http://predb.me?post=7517049">The.Repair.Shop.S04E02.720p.WEBRip.x264-LiGATE</a></h2>
            <a rel="nofollow" href="http://predb.me?post=7517049" class="tb tb-perma" title="Visit the permanent page for this release."></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="post" id="7517048">
    <div class="p-head">
        <div class="p-c p-c-time"><span class="p-time" data="1554740951" title="2019-04-08 @ 20:59:11 ( Your Time )"><span class="t-n-m">47</span> <span class="t-u">mins</span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="p-c p-c-cat"><span class="p-cat c-24 c-25 "><a href="http://predb.me?cats=books" class="c-adult">Books</a><a href="http://predb.me?cats=books-ebooks" class="c-child">eBooks</a></span></div>
        <div class="p-c p-c-title">
            <h2><a class="p-title" href="http://predb.me?post=7517048">John.Bell.Young.Puccini.A.Listeners.Guide.Dover.Books.on.Music.and.Music.History.2016.RETAiL.ePub.eBook-VENTOLiN</a></h2>
            <a rel="nofollow" href="http://predb.me?post=7517048" class="tb tb-perma" title="Visit the permanent page for this release."></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="post" id="7517047">
    <div class="p-head">
        <div class="p-c p-c-time"><span class="p-time" data="1554740927" title="2019-04-08 @ 20:58:47 ( Your Time )"><span class="t-n-m">48</span> <span class="t-u">mins</span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="p-c p-c-cat"><span class="p-cat c-5 c-6 "><a href="http://predb.me?cats=tv" class="c-adult">TV</a><a href="http://predb.me?cats=tv-sd" class="c-child">SD</a></span></div>
        <div class="p-c p-c-title">
            <h2><a class="p-title" href="http://predb.me?post=7517047">The.Repair.Shop.S04E01.WEB.h264-LiGATE</a></h2>
            <a rel="nofollow" href="http://predb.me?post=7517047" class="tb tb-perma" title="Visit the permanent page for this release."></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

at the top we have 3 main div that contain another div , actually for example i give the value of `<a>` tag in the 3th main div and the value is `The.Repair.Shop.S04E01.WEB.h264-LiGATE` and i want next time that my script reload the page find the `The.Repair.Shop.S04E01.WEB.h264-LiGATE` in the page and select previous div that has `<span>` that has `<a>` via TV value actually in the real page of the site i need select previous element just have `<a>` via TV value. in the example html the 1th div has TV value but 2th is not . is there any idea for this ?

the python codes i tryed :

```
my_soup = Wsoup(my_driver, "html.parser")


last_rls = input("Please Insert starter Release From Predb.me ::::")


previous_rls = my_soup.find("a", text=last_rls)

print(previous_rls)
Entry= previous_rls.parent.parent.parent.parent


previous_rls_parent = Entry.find_previous_sibling("div",{"class":"post"})

print(previous_rls_parent)
```

the python code can show previous element but i need to show the previous  elemenet that contain the `<a>` tag via TV value

Comment: beautiful soup has the concept of parent/children tags which might be what you want, but you'd get more help (and less downvotes) if you post some sample python code that you used to try and solve the problem.

Comment: @Chris alright i edit post and add my python codes

Comment: @Chris please check out

Comment: Given the search you have suggested, please [edit] the question to show what your expected output should be for that HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to display the text from the 3 `<div>` elements for the post you have searched for, you could try the following approach:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

search = "The.Repair.Shop.S04E01.WEB.h264-LiGATE"
soup = BeautifulSoup(my_driver, "html.parser")

rls = soup.find("a", text=search)
div_parent = rls.find_previous('div', class_='p-head')

for div in div_parent.find_all('div'):
    print(div.get_text(strip=True))
```

This displays the following 3 items:

```
48mins
TVSD
The.Repair.Shop.S04E01.WEB.h264-LiGATE
```